# Disabling NVIDIA Geforce MX230

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card

I have two Graphics Card. Discrete NVIDIA Geforce MX230 and  Integrated Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620. I recently installed Arch Linux and faced high battery consumption issue and heat. Did some google search and turns out Linux support to Hybrid Graphics are Experimental. I just browse some normal stuff so so I need to Disable Nvidia card and only use Intel to consume power. If Uninstalling Nvidia drivers is a solution, please provide steps!( I dont  have the option to disable it in the BIOS)

Comment: Why can't you take the lid off the case, and physically remove the card?

Comment: @spikey_richie  I am new to this field,  I don't know how to work with hardware stuffs and I also have a Windows 10 OS, So Taking it out , is not a solution!

Comment: It's a laptop from what I understand. It's most likely not modular. // Unless you explicitly set up Optimus (NVIDIA switchable graphics), the NVIDIA card would simply never be used, IIRC.

Comment: @Daniel B , The thing is I don't know this would be a problem before Installation. So I did Install propreitory drivers for NVIDIA using ' pacman -S nvidia-lts nvidia'